# How can I connect my local mysql database to Apache superset in MacBook Pro?

Tags: mysql, apache-superset

I am using [mysql://root:root@localhost:3306/db_superset](http://mysql://root:root@localhost:3306/db_superset) as the SqlAlchemy URI to connect mysql database to superset. However, I keep receiving error message like

[image]

Can anyone know how to resolve it? My OS version is macOS High Sierra Veresion 10.13.6.

Answer (score 0):

i think you don't have that python module installed previously, just run:

```
pip install mysqlclient
```

or if you are using python 2 then:

```
pip install mysql-python
```